# flash playback in chrome stuttering when switching tabs

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, flash-player

Today I noticed that my flash player under chrome pauses for a fraction of a second when switching tabs, and replays the previous several miliseconds of sound and video from before the switch.

I have done no administrative operations in my system **except updating Skype** - during which I accidentaly clicked next in the last phase of the update, where I should've probably unchecked some checkboxes (chrome homepage got changed, default search has changed).

I have checked [chrome release log](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/) and there have been no updates which could have caused the problem.

I strongly suspect that M$ skype update has somehow tinkered with chrome and "broke" it.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing Chrome? Set up Chrome Sync (if you haven't already) to make this process quick and easy.

Comment: @happy_soil I have not, but it seems like a tiresome process, I hope that a simple "change XXX in config" solution can be found

Comment: It literally takes under a minute to set up (you just have to sign-in to your Google account). Once its done, it'll sync up all your stuff up in Google servers. If you don't want to go this route, check your plugins by typing "chrome://plugins" in the address box. See if you could find any entries relating to Skype, and disable them. Then restart chrome.